MessageBox Hides the Parent Window Under Other Open Windows When Closing in WPF/Winform Application
I have been battling with this problem for so long now. I thought I would eventually figure out what was wrong, but it turned out that I couldn't.
It is this occasional occurrence with my app that I can't get my head around. When I use the MessageBox to display a message to the User and the user closes the MessageBox, the closing MessageBox causes the parent window of the app to disappear. Initially, I was like, "Hey what's going on here?" but on checking again, I see that the parent window just went under some already open windows. Then I will have to bring it back up again.
This happens whether the MessageBox is okayed, canceled or the 'X' close button is pressed. And, as I said, this only happens occasionally. I need to understand what causes this behavior so I can take control of it. Please somebody should give me a hint about what's happening.

Hi,@nomacreates. Not sure what your code is, you can follow the steps below to see if that helps. 1.When the MessageBox is closed, focus may not return to the parent window correctly, causing it to appear hidden behind other windows. You could try explicitly setting focus back to the parent window after the MessageBox is closed.
MessageBox.Show("Message")this.Focus(); 
2.   You can set the Z-order (stacking order) of the parent window to try to bring the parent window to the front after the MessageBox is closed.
MessageBox.Show("Message"); this.Topmost = true;

3.Make sure there are no event handlers or other code that could affect the parent window's visibility or Z-order when the MessageBox is closed.
4.Check for any application-level settings or configurations that may affect window behavior, such as window styles or window owner settings.  If the problem persists, could you show a minimal, reproducible example without private information so I can reproduce the problem? What are the steps to reproduce the current issue?

@HuiLiu-MSFT okay. I will try these right away! Many thanks.

@HuiLiu-MSFT I managed to try some of these but didn't help. But the MessageBox I was using was actually System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox and on changing it to System.Windows.MessageBox I noticed the problem didn't happen again. So it seems the issue was caused by mixing up System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox with a WPF project instead of using System.Windows.MessageBox. I am still testing thoroughly to be sure. Many thanks again.

Hi,@ nomacreates.Is there any updates? Is this issue indeed caused by mixing System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox with WPF project? Has the problem been solved?

@HuiLiu-MSFT, I really can't say for sure. But since changing from System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox to System.Windows.MessageBox, the problem never showed up again!

Okay.  Generally speaking, if there are no special requirements, it is recommended to use WPF controls in WPF projects.
